# Is there a reason that many database admins use sizes of 2^n when creating database tables?

Tags: mysql, database, size, allocation

Whenever I look through SQL table descriptions, I pretty much always see column data sizes of 2^n. (e.g. 8, 16, 64, 256, etc).  I know that due to the nature of binary and the fact that bytes are 8 bits long, 2^n is common to use in computing.  But does it actually make any difference in defining a SQL table?

If I have a column in a table called "FULL_NAME", and I want to give some room for a fairly long name, I would do

```
FULL_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
```

in my `create table` statement.  But I rarely see this in other people's tables.  For this example, I would probably see

```
FULL_NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
```

used instead.

Is there some actual advantage to using the next-highest 2^n value?  It seems like that is pointlessly allocating more space to a column just for the sake of having a number that feels like a computer would like it better.  I would imagine the column space allocation would be smart enough to not have to waste a bunch of space every time you don't enter a size of 2^n.

Comment: With varchar, no extra space would be wasted anyway; but yeah, as far as I know I would classify such behavior as superstitious optimization... **especially when it comes to VARCHAR**.

Comment: For VARCHAR, it doesn't make any difference because the size can be varied based on the content. "50" means anything 0-50 bytes plus 1 additional byte for end character whereas "64 means anything 0-64 bytes plus 1 additional byte for end character. On the other hand, CHAR is fixed, 64 means 64 bytes are used regardless of the content. So I'd think if it's CHAR, power of 2 may be better? If you care very much about the space, there is MySQL internal manual - it explains page and record levels http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb.html. There are additional bytes used internally.